# How can I use Cloud Storage as a Media Server without caching entire file before playback?

Tags: caching, google-drive-api, video-streaming, cloud-storage

TL:DR - How can I stream content (specifically music and videos) from a Cloud Storage solution, like Google Drive without having the entire file cached first? My goal is to create a Netflix/YouTube-esque experience with my movie/music library.

So, this seems to be an issue that many people are having, and so many forum posts say that PlexCloud is the solution, but it isn't available anymore, so I want to find another way.

Essentially, I would like to free up space on my local machine, offloading my movies and music to the cloud. I would like these files to be available instantly from any of my devices.

The solutions I have come across so far are:

- Google File Stream (or similar)
- Expandrive
- CloudMounter

These apps mount your cloud storage as a network drive and allow you to store files on the cloud and have "instant" access. These sound great in prinicple, but the issue with all of them is that the **entire** file has to be cached first before you can watch/listen. This  defeats the whole purpose of having the files saved to the cloud, as every time you want to watch a video, the entire file has to be cached. This is very inconvenient for me, as I have a rather slow internet connection, monthly transfer limits, and you have to wait until the file has been cached before you can watch.

The closest I've got to making this work is with Kodi, but the interface is horrible on anything other than a TV. On desktop or mobile, it's useless! But, as far as functionality, the way it retrieves files is perfect. On their website, it says that it only caches up to ~60MB at a time, meaning you can start watching/listening instantly, and the file doesn't need to be cached in its entirety.

So my questions are:

1. Is there an alternative to Kodi that works on all major OS's, where the files are instantly available and the caching system works like YouTube, Netflix, where only a small portion of the file is cached at once?
2. Is it actually possible to play a video natively in the OS (in an app like VLC) before the entire video is stored on the local disk, either in storage or in cache?
3. If so, how would I go about doing this?

A few conditions for the solution:

- I don't want to have to use the browser every time - A desktop/mobile app, Finder, or File Explorer is essential.
- Ideally something that will run on Android TV, or at least is able to use Chromecast.
- Files must be instantly accessible - nothing that will cache the entire file first (unless this is impossible due to how OS's work).
- If possible, I would prefer NOT to have to go through some massively complicated set up with coding, terminal commands, or using a dedicated server. The solution must use cloud storage, ideally with an app that works on major OS's.

Thanks in advance for help and suggestions!

Comment: Would love to help but your question is too broad and not specifically about coding which is what this Stack Overflow is for. You might be able to try [another stack site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) like super user, server fault or web apps - though I would try to at least split up the question into a few different ones to get a better chance of being answered.

Comment: @iansedano thanks for the reply. didn't realise this stack site was coding specific. I'll post in one of the others